# Converting a string passed through HTTP GET to an integer

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to convert a string, passed through a query string, into an integer in order to perform multiplication on it and pass it to `expired_date` to change the date and time.

```
ed = params.fetch 'expired_date'
ex = ed.to_i
expired_date = (Time.now + ex * 24 * 60 )
```

In my browser, I typed:

```
/expired_date="2"
```

when doing the checking:

```
ed show "2"
ed.instance_of? String show "true"
ex show 0
expired_date show [the current date and time]
```

I wanted the result:

```
ed show "2"
ex show 2
expired_date show [current date + 2 days]
```

I don't understand why it can't be converted to an integer.

Comment: maybe `ed` is not equal to "2", you can test `ed == "2"`

Comment: I have checked. It turns out ed is not equal to "2"
But when I puts ed it show "2" and I checked instance_of ed is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `ed` is not a string `2`, it is a string `"2"`. If you try to call `to_i` on `"2"` in your console, you'll see why you're getting `0`:

```
ed = '"2"'
#=> "\"2\""

ed.to_i
#=> 0
```

You need to remove the double quotes from the string before calling `to_i`. One approach to this is to remove the first and last character using:

```
ex = ed[1...-1].to_i
#=> 2
```

Another is to use `gsub`:

```
ex = ed.gsub('"', '').to_i
#=> 2
```

But you should probably look into passing the parameter without the quotes, if it's intended to be used as an integer in your application.

Comment: Thank you! what a silly mistake for me.
I change the syntax in the web to 
    /expired_date=2
Is ok now.

Comment: @Dennis: The difference between a string delimited by double quotes and a string containing double quotes can be subtle sometimes when working with HTTP. :-)

Comment: I agree, Because I manually assign the value to expired_date, I thought I need to use the double quoto to assign into it. It turns out not the case.